# access dataset filled in page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a Dataset that I fill with two sql tables in the Page_Load event. I fill my DropDownList ddlAirport00 with the values ​​of the first table. But I can not access the filled dataset from the ddlAirport00_SelectedIndexChanged(). It's like the dataset is empty or a Scope of variables trouble. 
Someone can help me?

```
        public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    }
```

my Page_Load

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                //this.ds = new DataSet();
                sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Aeropuerto", scon);
                sda.Fill(ds, "Aeropuerto");

                sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from ALocalidad", scon);
                sda.Fill(ds, "Localidad");

                sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Tramo", scon);
                sda.Fill(ds, "Tramo");
            }
}
```

And My DDL SelectedIndexChanged() ** I Use Ajax to change the testeeric.Text

```
 protected void ddlAirport00_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ds.Tables.Contains("Tramo"))
        {
               testeeric.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            testeeric.Text = "Brasil";
        }
}
```

Comment: please add some more codes here. it will helpful for others to understand your question.

Comment: This is classic asp.net. page load and selectedindexchanged method have different context. You must get the dataset fron db again or sort some caching...

Comment: Each time the page posts back, you're hitting a new instance of the Page class. That means that any fields (variables specific to a class instance) will be new for each request. You can't use them to persist values across requests. You'll either need to cache the data somewhere, or requery for the values.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid other SQL connections. 
is there no way to get the dataset by reference?

Comment: You can cache the data, that will avoid needing to re-query for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data retrieving logic is located inside `if (!IsPostBack)`, it is called only at initial page load.

So, you will need to retrieve the data from database again inside `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

```
protected void ddlAirport00_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   String CS = CnfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
       ["MyDatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
   using (SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(CS))
   {
      sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Tramo", scon);
      sda.Fill(ds, "Tramo");

      // Do something.

      if (ds.Tables.Contains("Tramo"))
      {
          testeeric.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
      }
      else
      {
          testeeric.Text = "Brasil";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I might suggest showing how to use a method to contain the common logic rather than copy/pasting the logic into multiple places.

Comment: I can not fill  the public Dataset and access it in any event?

Comment: @Feijuca Http is state less, so it could not maintain data from previous request. If you want to do the way you described, you should not use `if (!IsPostBack)` inside `Page_Load` event.

Comment: Thanks @Win now I understand